# marshalling decimal.Decimal in golang

Tags: json, go, decimal, marshalling

I am using github.com/shopspring/decimal for money operations (Numbers with precision)

What is the best way to marshalling a decimal.Decimal and unmarshallin and get the same value ?

Is a way to convert decimal.Decimal to string ?

Thank.

Answer (score 3):

`decimal.Decimal` implements the `Stringer` interface.

Therefore, to convert *to* a string, where `d` is a `decimal.Decimal`:

```golang
s := d.String()
```

To obtain a `decimal.Decimal` *from* a string, use `decimal.NewFromString()`:

```golang
d, err := decimal.NewFromString(s)
if err != nil {
    // handle err
}
```

Note also that `decimal.Decimal` will marshal to JSON as a `string` by default (that is, a double-quoted representation).  *Un*marshalling automatically supports quoted (string) or non-quoted (number) values.

The marshalling behaviour can be controlled by setting `decimal.MarshalJSONWithoutQuotes` to `true` if desired.  e.g. if interacting with an API that requires/expects a number value in a JSON payload.

There are two things to be aware of here:

1. this setting affects the marshalling of *all* `decimal.Decimal` values.  There appears to be no way to marshal with/without quotes on a case-by-case basis selectively
2. marshalling without quotes may result in a silent loss of precision

There is no need to "control" the *un*marshalling behaviour.  a `decimal.Decimal` will be unmarshalled from either a (correctly encoded) `string` or `number` value, as needed.

There is no loss of precision resulting from *unmarshalling* a `number` (aside from any loss occurring as a result of the original marshalling *to* that number value).

Answer (score 2):

`decimal.Decimal` implements the `json.Marshaler` interface and the `json.Unmarshaler` interface. `json.Marshal()` calls its `MarshalJSON` method to produce JSON; while `json.Unmarshal()` calls its `UnmarshalJSON` method to parse the JSON-encoded data. So, you do not need to do it explicitly.

Comment: There are not insignificant problems that can occur if you take marshalling and unmarshalling as always handled implicitly. For example, floats are not the same as strings: `fmt.Println(decimal.NewFromFloat(1.0000000000000001)
, "!=", decimal.NewFromString("1.0000000000000001"))`